# How to create Team base Report in CRM 2011

Tags: ssrs-2008, dynamics-crm-2011, fetchxml

I want to create case report in Dynamics CRM 2011.
That show all cases of a Team.

How can I filter this filter in fetch-XML Query.

Comment: did you try to start using the report wizard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options:

1. You can set enableprefiltering="true" on your Team entity: `<entity name="team" enableprefiltering="true">` This will allow the user to select which Teams to run the query against using Advanced Find like functionality. They can also execute reports like this from the Team List View or Form to automatically filter the results by the selected Team records.
2. You can create a @Team parameter. Get the Available Values from a fetchxml query that selects each team name for the Label, and the teamid for the Value. Then in your main query, add a filter to the team enity:

`<filter type="and">
  <condition attribute="teamid" operator = 'in' value="@Team"/>
 </filter>`